# Как вывести сотни тысяч небольших объектов из бд?

Tags: spring, orm

Как лучше всего обеспечить такой вывод?

Объекты не большие два поля. Но надо сделать это быстро. И чтобы было эффективно с точки зрения памяти.

Необходимо использовать **Spring** и любую **ORM**.

Может как-то кешировать? Как организовать запросы?

Бд - **postgres**.

Comment: Какая у вас БД? Какие наработки есть?

Comment: Кроме промапленой entity с двумя полемя и скрипта для создания таблицы бд где одно из полей id является ключём ничего нету. Важно найти наиболее оптимальное решение. Плюс ко всему думаю что кеш тут не нужен бд postgres.

Answer (score 1):

ORM внутри себя так или иначе используют так называемые DataReader'ы, которые идут по набору и возвращают результат.

Поэтому, если перед вами стоит задача просто вернуть строки, то разницы особой не будет.

Разница между ORM и голыми запросами могла бы быть, если бы вы использовали бы сложные соединения, так как ORM обычно генерируют не самые оптимальные запросы.

Comment: Ну если объемы маленькие они приносят свои дивиденды. Но если объемы данных большие стоит ли их использовать?

Comment: @alexsafsafsd, лично я не вижу смысла в ORM, если есть всего несколько сущностей. Разве что какую-нибудь MICRO ORM, вроде, Dapper использовать. Во многих ORM отсутствует BulkInsert, который выручает при вставках большого кол-ва данных.